# Installing mono on lubuntu - code package needs to be reinstalled

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mono, ubuntu-16.04, monodevelop

I am fairly new to ubuntu and I've installed lubuntu 17.04 since I needed a lightweight OS for an old laptop I have.
Since I need to develop some c# apps I knew that I couldn't install VS Community on ubuntu but there had to be some alternatives and after some research I found about mono.
Going to the downoad page on mono website http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin I've found the procedure I had to do to install mono so I've followed it step-by-step:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mono-devel
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
sudo apt-get install mono-dbg
```

after I've done that last step I was asked to fix the installation by doing: `apt --fix-broken install`

And after that I proceeded to install the rest of the packages as referred on the website:`sudo apt-get install referenceassemblies-pcl`
and I got the following error: dpkg was interrupted, to correct the problem run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
After trying to reinstall that last package I get the following message:

> The package code needs to be reinstalled but a repository couldn't be found

After some research I couldn't find anything related to that package and I tried to perform the above steps again but I got the same result.
Where can I find that package or what do I need to do to resume the installation of mono?
Thanks in advance

PS: I'm sorry if the errors aren't 100% as they appear in the console because my distro in portuguese and I've translated the messages the best I knew.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww you're correct and Im sorry. Is there any way an admin could port this question to the appropriate slack?

Comment: On resource limited environments, you might try Visual Studio Code + .NET Core SDK.

Comment: if possible I'd really like to have an IDE instead of an editor. IDE is the way to go when it comes to OOP in my opinion. the extra features are really handy and a good debugger is a must have